# How to click on a radio button in selenium webdriver using javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, radio-button

I am trying to run a test script that will click a radio button. The radio button elements are inside a div.

Here is the javascript code:

```
var driver = new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
await driver.get("URL");
var selectGender = driver.findElement(By.css("div[class='gender-select-child'] label[for='male-child0']"));
await selectGender.click();
```

HTML snapshot:

[image: HTML code]

Hoping for a resolve.

Comment: Much better if you use the label id for selecting the element :
e.g
By.css("#gender-radio-parent")

In case you want to select the radio button better apply click on the input not label in this case so By.css("#male-child0")

Answer (score 0):

To click on the [radio-button](/questions/tagged/radio-button) with text as ***Male*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
var driver = new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
await driver.get("URL");
var selectGender = driver.findElement(By.css("div[class='gender-select-child'] input[id^='male']"));
await selectGender.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to click the radio button using this syntax...

```
await driver.findElement(By.css("label[for='female-child0']")).click();
```

However, I need to use it twice for it to work. My script looks like this...

[image: Javascript snap]

Any idea why?